# Undefined error while trying to retrieve User by email address(axios and react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I am trying to retrieve a specific user by their email but I am getting this error

> ccess to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/calorie_counter/email.undefined' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I presume that it has something to do with the useParams not being recognized by the axios request and I have done something wrong there.

[image: This is how the the page looks]

this is the code for this page

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom'

export default function ViewUser() {
  
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        name:"",
        email: "",
        dob: "",
        age: "",
        suggestedCalories: "",
        goal:"",
        lifestyle:"",
        weight:""
    });

    const { email } = useParams();

    const onInputChange = (e) => {
        setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
      };

    

    useEffect(()=>{
        
    }, [])
  
    const onSubmit = async (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/calorie_counter/email.${email}`)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
      }
    return (
    <div className='col-md-6 offset-md-3 border rounded p-4 mt-2 shadow'>
        <form onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
        <div className='mb-3'>
            <label htmlFor='Email' className='form-label'>
            E-mail
            </label>
            <input
            type={'text'}
            className='form-control'
            placeholder='Enter E-mail'
            onChange= {(e) => onInputChange(e)}
            value={email}
            
            
            />
            <button type="submit" className='btn btn-outline-success'>Submit</button>
        </div>
        </form>
    <div className='card'>
        <div className='card-header'>
            Details of user id : 
            <ul className='list-group list-group-flush'>
                <li className='list-group-item'>
                    <b>Name: </b>
                    {user.name}
                </li>
                <li className='list-group-item'>
                    <b>Email: </b>
                    {user.email}
                </li>
                <li className='list-group-item'>
                    <b>Date of Brith: </b>
                    {user.dob}
                </li>
                <li className='list-group-item'>
                    <b>Age: </b>
                    {user.age}

                </li>
                <li className='list-group-item'>
                    <b>Suggested Calories: </b>
                    {user.suggestedCalories}

                </li>
                <li className='list-group-item'>
                    <b>Goal: </b>
                    {user.goal}

                </li>
                <li className='list-group-item'>
                    <b>LifeStyle: </b>
                    {user.lifestyle}

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
    
  )
}
```

I am expecting to type an email of an existing user in the database, click submit and receive the use by its Email. I know the backend work so it is only the Frontend that has problems. I have tried to mess around with the input field but it did not work. It is either something wrong with the input field or the submit button

Comment: Why do you mix fetch and axios? Should be `.then(res=>res.json())`

Comment: "The backend work" does not mean it cannot get CORS issues. How are you setting up your CORS in backend and axios? What framework are you using?

Comment: @Konrad sorry that was the old version of the code I just updated it, this version I did use
> .then(res=>res.json())

Comment: @Divyessh I am using spring boot for the backend. the reason why I think it is not the backend is that I think it is not reading the email I enter after I click the submit button. because it is saying email.undefined and the URL is email.{email} for my @GetMapping URL. So the it is most likely that the email is not being set to axios request 
axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/calorie_counter/email.${email}`)

Comment: @Divyesh no because I am pretty sure it's just the URL I'm using for axios that is the problem and I am just confused about how to set the {email} in the URL to the email I enter in the input. since it is saying http://localhost:8080/calorie_counter/email.undefined
it should be
http://localhost:8080/calorie_counter/email.SomeOne@domain.com
for example

Comment: @MilestoneFanatic why are you using - `const { email } = useParams();` if you want to get the email from user input?

Comment: @Divyesh I did that because I thought that would be able to set {email} for the axios URL. I thought it would be like a variable so that I would use {email} as the value and then it would carry to the URL. I was just trying anything at one point to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the `email` being `undefined` issue, you need to correctly use the onInputChange function like in the example below.
If you still receive a CORS issue, please let me know in comments.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom'

export default function ViewUser() {
  
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
        name:"",
        email: "",
        dob: "",
        age: "",
        suggestedCalories: "",
        goal:"",
        lifestyle:"",
        weight:""
    });


    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

    const onInputChange = (e) => {
        setEmail(e.target.value);
      };

    useEffect(()=>{
        
    }, [])
  
    const onSubmit = async (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/calorie_counter/email.${email}`)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
      }
    return (
    <div className='col-md-6 offset-md-3 border rounded p-4 mt-2 shadow'>
        <form onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
        <div className='mb-3'>
            <label htmlFor='Email' className='form-label'>
            E-mail
            </label>
            <input
            type={'text'}
            className='form-control'
            placeholder='Enter E-mail'
            onChange= {(e) => onInputChange(e)}
            value={email}
            
            
            />
            <button type="submit" className='btn btn-outline-success'>Submit</button>
        </div>
        </form>
    <div className='card'>
        <div className='card-header'>
            Details of user id : 
            <ul className='list-group list-group-flush'>
                <li className='list-group-item'>
                    <b>Name: </b>
                    {user.name}
                </li>
                <li className='list-group-item'>
                    <b>Email: </b>
                    {user.email}
                </li>
                <li className='list-group-item'>
                    <b>Date of Brith: </b>
                    {user.dob}
                </li>
                <li className='list-group-item'>
                    <b>Age: </b>
                    {user.age}

                </li>
                <li className='list-group-item'>
                    <b>Suggested Calories: </b>
                    {user.suggestedCalories}

                </li>
                <li className='list-group-item'>
                    <b>Goal: </b>
                    {user.goal}

                </li>
                <li className='list-group-item'>
                    <b>LifeStyle: </b>
                    {user.lifestyle}

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
    
  )
}
```

Comment: thank you, this was the answer to my problem. I really appreciate it